# What is difference between 2 package fcm-django and django-fcm

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm so confuse between 2 package fcm-django and django-fcm.

As i know, they are a firebase service to support notification in mobile type.

But both of packages have syntax and import ways are difference.
So i don't know what is benefit of them.

Could you compare both of them, plz.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

They're projects with roughly similar goals, developed by different people.

As of June of 2020 however, django-fcm [hasn't been updated since 2016](https://pypi.org/project/django-fcm/#history), while fcm-django is [receiving regular updates.](https://pypi.org/project/fcm-django/#history) I would probably use fcm-django if I were you, if only because it seems maintained.